# Quantify amount of oscillations in a time-series

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, time-series

I have a time-series and I'd like to find a way to measure how 'shaky' and basically have a statistic (or couple of statistics) that could describe that.

The standard-deviation isn't suitable because in the case of a very shaky time series but small variations, the standard deviation could still turn out to be very low.

Any suggestions on approaches that would be suitable here ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are seeing and what exactly you want to quantify?

Comment: I can give a sample of my time-series but this was more of a thought about general applications rather than for my specific case.

I was wondering if there's a way we can quantify the 'shakiness' of a time-series : Is it pretty much stable or does it go under and over it's mean too often.

Comment: You might find this thread useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3269080/how-can-you-mathematically-define-a-wobbly-function/3269101#3269101.

Comment: It's a good reading indeed. How would one adapt the proposed measures when there's no prior knowledge about the expression of the function 'f' ? For example if we only have a list of values ?
The first expression you gave in your answer seems to be the most suitable in that case but I still don't see how you would find the total variance.

Comment: @mjab: I would adapt my first expression to this (given data $\{x_i\}, \; 1\le i\le N$): $$\frac{\max_i(x_i)-\min_i(x_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}|x_{i+1}-x_i|}. $$

Answer (score 0):

I interpret „being shaky“ as: The differences between nearby samples are constantly swapping their sign.

This leads me to the suggestion: Model it using ARMA (autoregressive moving averages) models. These are models which check for differential or integrative relationships in the data. You can also apply these models on the absolute value of some kind of numerical derivative of the time series.

These work best when you already substracted trend and periodicity, so that the expectation of the trend is zero and there is no periodicity involved. Removing the trend can be done by fitting a suitable (its up to you to define that word) function to the time series. Periodicities can be found as peaks in the autocorrelation function or some kind of Fourier or wavelet transforms.

Another way could be just to normalize the variance of time series, or a combination of different approaches. The question is always: Can you interpret your mathematical tools in terms of the language of your data.